# Cannot install pyansys using pip install

Tags: python, pip, binaryfiles, ansys, pyansys

I am on Pycharm and wish to install the pyansys package, but I keep getting this error:

```
Collecting pyansys
  Using cached pyansys-0.61.3.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
     
      *** PyAnsys has moved (and expanded!) ***
     
      To use PyAnsys you need to install the applicable packages for your
      product:
     
      MAPDL:
     
      - ``pip install ansys-mapdl-core``
     
      MAPDL Post-Processing:
     
      - ``pip install ansys-mapdl-reader``
      - ``pip install ansys-dpf-core``
      - ``pip install ansys-dpf-reader``
     
      PyAEDT
     
      - ``pip install pyaedt``
     
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

So I went ahead and installed all but one of those packages. I also installed cython. The only package that cannot be installed is ansys-dpf-reader and here is its error message

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ansys-pdf-reader (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ansys-pdf-reader
```

What is going on?

Comment: Misspelling.  `dpf`, not `pdf`.

Comment: Actually I tried with both spellings and neither worked. I just pasted the error message for the pdf spelling because I tried it last.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ansys-dpf-reader (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ansys-dpf-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like 'ansys-dpf-reader' was changed to 'ansys-dpf-post' and the 'pyansys' is not a pacakge anymore, but has now expanded into these 5 packages. Installing all of them will allow the normal use of the old pyansys.

https://docs.pyansys.com/